# Caption of a table in an array-environment

Tags: captions, arrays

I used the array-environment to construct a table of data:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for top-,mid- & bottomrule

\begin{document}

    $
    \begin{array}{lcc}
        \toprule
            &\text{1\textsuperscript{st} growth period} & \text{2\textsuperscript{nd} growth period} \\
        \midrule
             \text{Estonia} & 1.28 & 1.72 \\
             \text{Slovenia} & 1.26 & 0.21 \\
             \text{Czech Republic} & 1.16 & 0.46 \\
             \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
             \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
        \hline
             \text{Mean} & 0.69 & 0.53 \\
             \text{Lower-Quantile} & 0.37 & 0.21 \\
             \text{Upper-Quantile} & 0.99 & 0.80\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    $
```

Now I would like to add a caption to my table. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you're not using a `tabular` for this, but if you want to add a caption, you can use `\captionof` from the `caption` package. Note that `\captionof` stands for 'caption outside float'

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for top-,mid- & bottomrule
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    $
    \begin{array}{lcc}
        \toprule
            &\text{1\textsuperscript{st} growth period} & \text{2\textsuperscript{nd} growth period} \\
        \midrule
             \text{Estonia} & 1.28 & 1.72 \\
             \text{Slovenia} & 1.26 & 0.21 \\
             \text{Czech Republic} & 1.16 & 0.46 \\
             \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
             \text{...} & \text{...} & \text{...} \\
        \hline
             \text{Mean} & 0.69 & 0.53 \\
             \text{Lower-Quantile} & 0.37 & 0.21 \\
             \text{Upper-Quantile} & 0.99 & 0.80\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    $
    \captionof{table}{My caption}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: I work with Mathematica, which exports tables only in the array-environment. That's why I did not use tabular.
Thank you for your answer! I think it will do it.